# Процессы и указатели в С Linux

Tags: linux, указатели, процесс

Доброго времени суток.
 Пытаюсь разобраться с устройством механизмов процессов, в частности с переменными. И возник вопрос. 
Есть следующий код:

```
pid_t pid1;
int i = 4;
int *pointer = &i;

void main ()
{
    pid1 = fork();  
    if(pid1 == 0)
    {
        i=i+2;
        pointer = &i;
        printf("child : pointer adress %p : i adress %p : pointer_value %d\n", &pointer, &i, *pointer); 
        exit(0);

    }
    if(pid1 > 0)
    {
        wait(0);
        printf("parent: pointer adress %p : i adress %p : pointer_value %d\n", &pointer, &i, *pointer);
    }
    return;
}
```

На выходе дает:

> ```
> child : pointer adress 0x601060 : i adress 0x601058 : pointer_value 6
> parent: pointer adress 0x601060 : i adress 0x601058 : pointer_value 4
> ```

Тогда почему pointer_value различны, если области памяти на которые они указывают одинаковы?

Comment: Про Windows, но всё равно полезно: http://bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1045&p=6784461#p6784461

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У каждого процесса свое пространство виртуальных адресов.

Два одинаковых адреса в разных процессах отображаются в разные физические адреса RAM, поэтому их содержимое разное.

---

Более углубленное знакомство с этой темой можно начать со статьи
[виртуальная память](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C) в вике.